# Can't install better-sqlite3 in order to run Discord bot

Tags: sqlite, npm, discord.js, raspberry-pi4, better-sqlite3

I'm using a raspberry pi 4 as well as Visual Studio Code to setup and run my bot. All of my packages were installed, except for `better-sqlite3`. I tried re-installing `node-gyp` (successfully installed) and then re-installing better-sqlite3 again, here is my error:

```sh
$npm i better-sqlite3
```

> - better-sqlite3@7.1.1 install /home/pi/Code/Waffles/node_modules/better-sqlite3
> - prebuild-install || npm run build-release
> - prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=14.15.0 runtime=node arch=arm libc= platform=linux)
> - better-sqlite3@7.1.1 build-release /home/pi/Code/Waffles/node_modules/better-sqlite3
> - node-gyp rebuild --release
> - make: Entering directory '/home/pi/Code/Waffles/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build'
>   TOUCH b857c92884e9598d609f6be182a2595df7a8e00f.intermediate
>   ACTION deps_sqlite3_gyp_locate_sqlite3_target_extract_sqlite3 b857c92884e9598d609f6be182a2595df7a8e00f.intermediate
>   TOUCH Release/obj.target/deps/locate_sqlite3.stamp
>   CC(target) Release/obj.target/sqlite3/gen/sqlite3/sqlite3.o

Answer (score 2):

## Windows

To fix this problem, open an **administrative** PowerShell window, and run

```sh
npm i -g --add-python-to-path --vs2015 --production windows-build-tools
```

Once thats done (it may take up to 30 minutes, depending on your internet and computer speed) restart your pc, and it should work

## Linux

To fix this on linux, run

```sh
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

and then install better-sqlite3.

## Mac

To fix this on mac, simply

```
 - Install [XCode][1]
 - Once XCode is installed, go to Preferences, Downloads, and install the Command Line Tools.
```

then better-sqlite should be installed correctly.

### Hope this helps!

***Note:** I've noticed you're a new contributor, first of all, welcome to StackOverflow, second of all, be sure to mark your question as solved by clicking the check next to the answer that helped you, so people know its solved.*

Answer (score 0):

That is not an error, It is the better-sqlite3 Installer, following errors could appear like this below

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-45-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /media/jeremiah/Discord bot/Discord bot/node_modules/better-sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: There was nothing like that. It stopped giving anything else and just left an unfunctional node terminal. The only thing i could do is close it. No errors like that were given